# GradleCompatible new version

Tags: android, gradle

Please can you help me to solve this problem, I don't know where is the problem I have all the updates

**The problem:**

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 28.0.0, 27.0.2. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and
>   com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2 less... (Ctrl+F1)  Inspection
>   info:There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries,
>   that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility
>   is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is
>   not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion).  Issue id: GradleCompatible

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.el.sohaib.babysitter"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'


    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
  //the erreur   implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.el.sohaib.babysitter"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'


    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning is shown because the Facebook sdk uses older versions of support libraries. It doesn't goes well this the newer version (28.0.0) that you are using in your project.

The Solution is to exclude all older versions of libraries used in Facebook sdk:

```
 implementation ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'customtabs'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-media-compat'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Excluding dependencies can causes run-time crashes because the library shall be calling functions in those excluded libraries.
Now you need to provide newer versions of all those libraries in your dependencies

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

Here is my complete build.gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

        /**
        * Providing newer versions of those libs
        */
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

        /**
        * Excluding older libs
        */
        implementation ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)') {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview-v7'
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'customtabs'
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-media-compat'
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        }

        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


    }
```